# RewriteRule `.htaccess` - change URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm searching since 4 hours and can't find a solution. I hope somebody can help me.

I want rewrite the URL with `.htaccess`.

I have this link in menue:`/index.php?sec=schmiede&mp=faq`

And I want to get this in the browser URL:`/schmiede/faq`

Thank you!
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect every request to index.php and handle your requests from there. Your .htaccess would look like;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You can handle the requests by calling $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] that will return "/schmiede/faq" then you can turn it to an array by using

```
$route = explode('/', ltrim('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

**Or** you could simply redirect that one request;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^schmiede/faq$ /index.php?sec=schmiede&mp=faq [L]
```

However, since your example shows a direct call to index.php, I would use the first as you would probably use the "nice urls" for all your links.

Comment: "RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^schmiede/faq$ /index.php?sec=schmiede&mp=faq [L]"

Thank you. I try it, but it don't make anything ;/ Any idea?

Comment: I've tested the latter option and it should work. Be sure you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server. .htaccess:
`RewriteEngine On` [linebreak] `RewriteRule ^schmiede/faq$ /index.php?sec=schmiede&mp=faq [L]` index.php: `<?php echo $_GET['sec'],'<br>',$_GET['mp'];` Tell me if it works. If not; do you have any other rules in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, this works. But I think you don´t know that I need. I want to make "nice URLs". So in my browser URL stands h t t p : / / w w w .../index.php?sec=schmiede&mp=faq and want to have h t t p : / / w w w .../schmiede/faq/ ... I hope it is now clearer. Thanks for you help

Comment: Yes, that's what this does. Try cleaning your browser's cache and try again, sometimes that's the problem. I tested the code in my previous comment and it works.

Comment: I've just seen that you want a "/" after "faq" So now you have to change the RewriteRule to `^schmiede/faq/$` So with the "/" added it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I have no "nice URL" it is always the same. In my htaccess is this:
RewriteEngine On [linebreak]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dieheldenschmiede\.de$ [linebreak]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dieheldenschmiede.de/$1 [R=permanent] [linebreak]
[linebreak]

RewriteBase / [linebreak]
RewriteRule ^schmiede/faq/$ /index.php?sec=schmiede&mp=faq [linebreak] If you go on the website (footer -> FAQ) you see the testlink. If you click on it no nice URL is to see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a problem with your code I think. Try this; http://jsfiddle.net/FLc9B/ Just copy the code from the HTML section and paste it in your .htaccess file and comment back if there're still problems. NOTE: I left out the trailing "/" after "faq" because I'm not sure if you want that or not.

Comment: I have replace it with your code - 121. But it is still the same - nothing ;/ To your questions: yes I want the "/" after "faq" AND I want non-www to www (the oposite). Thanky you!

Comment: I use this; jsfiddle.net/FLc9B/4 and all goes well on my side. Are you using something like Wordpress? Then it might be you get a redirect from there.

Comment: Thank you. Now the www works great. But no nice URL - same thing. The site is "handmade". So I'm sure were is no redirect etc. I have no idea ;/ Should it be a provider problem?

Comment: I don't think it's a provider problem although it's a possibility, but it's very unlikely. If you could paste your full code somewhere I could have a look at it.